# Why would Jyn Erso's voice be heard in this place?

Tags: star-wars

In *Star Wars Rebels* Season 4, episode 13 "A World Between Worlds" Ezra Bridger hears voices from characters from the past and future. While most are force users or at least have knowledge of the force (Maz Kanata) he also hears part of Jyn Erso’s speech on Yavin IV. Why would Jyn be heard here if she has shown no signs of being force sensitive? Looking mainly for an in-universe reason, out-of-universe it is a way to include all the movies released at that point.

Answer (score 5):

The World Between Worlds is a new plane of existence that isn't explained in the series or any supporting materials. That being said, it isn't connecting Ezra to specific Force-wielders. Rather, it's showing Ezra a discontinuous stream of events throughout time.

Jyn is heard (as are Finn, Poe, and others not yet part of the story) because of their involvement in important galactic events past, present, and yet-to-come, not because of their Force sensitivity.

Comment: Is this show awful? It sounds awful...